# Including CV in \documentlass{book}

Tags: cv

Hy,

I would like to include my CV written as `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}`to my PhD which is written as `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}`.

Is this even possible or I have to rewrite everything?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write two `documentclass` in one document. But you can include pdf in a document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf{CV}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Krsty if you found the answer helpful, you can validate it using the tick on the left side